# How to write / read plist in Swift 3

Tags: swift, applescript, plist

I have an AppleScript setting up the data for my Swift App.

Let's say the data is saved on the desktop, for example data.plist.

How can I read this data from my Swift app and set as a variable?

Comment: Or any other way to send the variable from AppleScript to Swift could be an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NSDictionary` API to read/write plist files. For example:

```
// given a value (fileURL) of type URL
// read plist
let nsDict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: fileURL)
// write plist
nsDict.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true)
```

[NSDictionary Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary)